# Disable checkbox by clicking another checkbox (HTML/DJANGO)

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes on my site. One of them gives me opportunity (or not) to click(change state) second one. So if first checkbox is checked I can change state of second but if first checkbox is unchecked then I just can't (checkbox is disabled).

So I wrote simple if/else statement in html (with django python) and it looks like :

```
{% if first.value %}
    {% if second.value %}
        <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
    {% else %}
        <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox">
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {% if second.turnOnOff %}
        <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"  checked="checked">
    {% else %}
        <input id="myCheck" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Maybe some of you are confused why I have if statement for second checkbox, I just check his last value from database to know that it was True or False. I checked that code and it doesn't work good. I mean If I refresh page after each change state of first checkbox it works but is should work all the time without refreshing page all the time. What I'm doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

After some comments I tried another solution - using javascript. So I create simple JS function

```
function change() 
{
        if (document.getElementById("myCheck").isDisabled) {
            document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = true;
        }
}
```

and change part with first checkbox to call it. Now it works but only for first call. I mean when I disable checkbox I can not enable it

Comment: You're trying to use python/django for something that you should use javascript for. JS is going to be the tool for making webpages dynamic and interactive. I don't think django can alter the DOM dynamically like you are trying to do.

Comment: @SuperStew please see update I used JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your python code runs on a server (that includes the template engine). Thus it will only respond to requests. Put simply your browser sends a request to the server, it executes your python code and responds with the rendered template that your browser will display. 
Clicking a checkbox only changes the DOM in your browser, no request will be sent to the server and your python code (including the template engine) will thus never be executed.

Now if you don't want to reload the whole page you will have to resort to Javascript. Attach an event handler to the first checkbox and change the DOM accordingly to either display or hide your second checkbox.

Note however that you should still validate the data you receive from your form as Javascript is executed client-side and should thus never be trusted.

#### Edit to address the JS part a little further

First of all note that this is a different problem and if you are getting stuck writing your JS part you should really just ask a new question.

However since this is somewhat related to the question here's some example JS code to illustrate what I was thinking of.

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first');

first.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var divElem = document.getElementById('toggle'); 
  if (this.checked){
    divElem.style.display = 'block'; 
  }
  else {
    divElem.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="first"><span>First</span><br>
<div id="toggle" class="hidden">
  <input type="checkbox" id="second"><span>Second</span>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36as9Lh1/

Note that this is just a very simple example and should most likely be extended for your exact use case. For example this currently let's you check the first checkbox, check the second checkbox and then uncheck the first checkbox again resulting in the second checkbox being checked when it isn't allowed to.

Comment: But I used a debugger, on this part of code and after change state of first one it goes where it should I mean debugger act like all works like charm. But it diddnt

Comment: For now It works like checkbox that after click I need refresh to see changed state. It is changed before refresh but displayed only after refresh

Comment: That should only be the case if you submit the form after (un)checking the first checkbox. That way your browser sends a POST request to your server and your code/django updates `first.value`. The next time you (your browser) requests the form it will go through the template rendering process again and your second checkbox will now be displayed/hidden accordingly.

Comment: I added a basic JS example for further illustration of what I was talking about. Please note that this is a different problem and you should consider asking a new question if you get stuck writing the JS code.

Answer (score 1):

About your JavaScript: isDisabled is a function, so it will always return true the way you have it (that is, it is not `null`, `0`, or `false`). Just add `()`:

```
function change() {
    if (document.getElementById("myCheck").isDisabled()) {
        document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Or better yet:

```
function change() {
    var el = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    el.disabled = !el.isDisabled();
}
```

Comment: first function doesn't work eathier, but I change first line to `document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled === true` and now it works. This function .isDisabled() have really strange behaviour